# I am trying to fetch a field from a csv file as dropdown in HTML based form, but in the dropdown nothing is showing

Tags: php, html, csv

I am trying to fetch a field from a csv file as dropdown in HTML based form, but in the dropdown nothing is showing.

I have placed all the 3 files in the same location in my web hosting, but still the 'Petrol Pump Name' is not getting fetched from the csv file.

I wanted ';' (semicolon) as delimiter in the csv file

**HTML code (test.html) -**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Registration Form</title>
    <style>
        .container {
            max-width: 400px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        .form-group {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        label {
            display: block;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }

        input[type="text"],
        select {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 8px;
            border-radius: 4px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }

        input[type="submit"] {
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 4px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        input[type="submit"]:hover {
            background-color: #45a049;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Registration Form</h2>
        <form action="process.php" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="mobile">Mobile Number:</label>
                <input type="text" id="mobile" name="mobile" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pump">Petrol Pump Name:</label>
                <select id="pump" name="pump" required>
                    <option value="">Select Pump</option>
                    <?php include 'process.php'; ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP code (process.php) -**

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
    $pump = $_POST['pump'];

    // Perform any further processing or validation here

    // Redirect or display a success message
    header('Location: success.html');
    exit;
}

$file = fopen('pumps.csv', 'r');
if ($file !== false) {
    $pumpNames = [];
    while (($row = fgetcsv($file, 0, ';')) !== false) {
        $pumpName = $row[0];
        $pumpNames[] = $pumpName;
    }
    fclose($file);

    foreach ($pumpNames as $pumpName) {
        echo '<option value="' . $pumpName . '">' . $pumpName . '</option>';
    }
}
?>
```

**CSV file (pumps.csv) contents -**

| petrol pump name; | google coordinates |
| --- | --- |
| Pump A; | 12.34567,98.76543 |
| Pump B; | 23.45678,87.65432 |
| Pump C; | 34.56789,76.54321 |

Comment: You could use var_dump(variable) and go through your script to check if you are actually parsing the CSV.

Answer (score 0):

**With Javascript, I am able to get the names in the dropdown -**

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var pumpDropdown = document.getElementById('pump');

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'pumps.csv');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            var csvData = xhr.responseText;
            var rows = csvData.split('\n');
            var optionsHtml = '';
            for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
                var row = rows[i].trim();
                if (row !== '') {
                    var columns = row.split(';');
                    var pumpName = columns[0].trim();
                    optionsHtml += '<option value="' + pumpName + '">' + pumpName + '</option>';
                }
            }
            pumpDropdown.innerHTML += optionsHtml;
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
});
```

**Updated HTML File --**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Registration Form</title>
    <style>
        .container {
            max-width: 400px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        .form-group {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        label {
            display: block;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }

        input[type="text"],
        select {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 8px;
            border-radius: 4px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }

        input[type="submit"] {
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 4px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        input[type="submit"]:hover {
            background-color: #45a049;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Registration Form</h2>
        <form action="process.php" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="mobile">Mobile Number:</label>
                <input type="text" id="mobile" name="mobile" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pump">Petrol Pump Name:</label>
                <select id="pump" name="pump" required>
                    <option value="">Select Pump</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).